# Как выравнять элемент по центру?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как выравнять элемент по центру, если у него display:inline-block, свойство text-align:center не работает.
Структура что-то вроде такого

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="event" style="float:left">
    ....
   </div>
    <div class="div1">
     <div class="div1_1>
      ....
     </div>
     <div class="div1_2>
      .....
     </div>
     <div class="div1_3>
      ....
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Какой именно элемент надо равнять?

Comment: подправил... нужно выравнять элемент div1 по центру

Comment: а с классом event что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: У класса event float:left и все

Comment: Это понятно, но как он расположен? Прижат слева к родительскому или как?

Comment: Как должны располагаться div event и div div1 по отношению друг к другу и по отношению к родительскому div?

Comment: div event прижат к левой стороне по отношению от div1, а div1 должен быть расположен в центре родительского div, т.е. div class="parent"

Comment: Задайте родительскому div.parent ширину, так же задайте ширину для div.div1 и margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приходится ванговать ... как обычно на [flexbox](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent,
.div_1 {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.event {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.div_1 {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.div_1 * {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="event">
    event
  </div>
  <div class="div_1">
    <div class="div_1_1">
      div_1_1
    </div>
    <div class="div_1_2">
      div_1_2
    </div>
    <div class="div_1_3">
      div_1_3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**всё остальное оставил на своё усмаотрение**

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через `margin: 0 auto;`, или через flexbox `display: flex;
    align-items: center;
justify-content: center;`